# Convert First character of each word to upper case

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, title-case

I have a String and I need to convert the first letter of each word to upper case and rest to lower case using xsl, For example,

Input String= dInEsh sAchdeV kApil Muk

Desired Output String= Dinesh Sachdev Kapil Muk

Although, I know I have to use translate function for the purpose but how can I translate the first charter of each word to Upper-case and rest all in lower- case using XSLT 1.0

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following is not "nice", and I'm sure somebody (mainly Dimitri) could come up with something far simpler (especially in XSLT 2.0)... but I've [tested this and it works](http://www.xmlplayground.com/94P8gA)

```
<xsl:template name="CamelCase">
  <xsl:param name="text"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($text,' ')">
      <xsl:call-template name="CamelCaseWord">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-before($text,' ')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="CamelCase">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,' ')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="CamelCaseWord">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="CamelCaseWord">
  <xsl:param name="text"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($text,1,1),'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')" /><xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($text,2,string-length($text)-1),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')" />
</xsl:template>
```

The basic idea is that you call `CamelCase`, if it find a space, then it runs `CamelCaseWord` on everything *before* the space (i.e. the first word) and then calls `CamelCase` again with the everything *after* the space (i.e. the rest of the sentence).  Otherwise if no space is found (because it's got to the last word in the sentence), then it just calls `CamelCaseWord`.

The `CamelCaseWord` template simply translates the first character from lower to upper (if necessary) and all remaining characters from upper to lower (if necessary).

So to call it you'd have...

```
<xsl:call-template name="CamelCase">
   <xsl:with-param name="text">dInEsh sAchdeV kApil Muk</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This really help me to translate first character to upper. But this one assumes space in between strings. How can I dynamically find any non-alphanumeric letter instead of space and capitalise first letter. For e.g O'connel will be O'Connel and dave-manel will be Dave-Manel

Comment: @Patty - it's been a long time since I've done XSLT. I'm afraid I'm unable to answer your supplementary question. You'd be better off asking it as a brand new question. Sorry I can't be of more help

Comment: Thats fine no worries and thank you for your response.

Answer (score 5):

**Additional:**

I missed the 1.0 requirement in the question. This will only work from version 2.0.

Original answer below here.

I believe this one worked for me a while ago. Declare a function:

```
<xsl:function name="my:titleCase" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="s" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="lower-case($s)=('and','or')">
            <xsl:value-of select="lower-case($s)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$s=upper-case($s)">
            <xsl:value-of select="$s"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(upper-case(substring($s, 1, 1)), lower-case(substring($s, 2)))"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>
```

And use it:

```
<xsl:sequence select="string-join(for $x in tokenize($text,'\s') return my:titleCase($x),' ')"/>
```

credit goes to **samjudson** => http://p2p.wrox.com/xslt/80938-title-case-string.html

Comment: OP has the `xslt-1.0` tag... `lower-case` and `upper-case` is not available in 1.0

Comment: @freefaller Ooh, missed that. Wil change answer to reflect this for future reference. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Here is a 8 years old FXSL 1.x (an XSLT 1.0 libray written completely in XSLT 1.0) solution:**

test-strSplit-to-Words10.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
>
   <xsl:import href="strSplitWordDel.xsl"/>

   <!-- To be applied on: test-strSplit-to-Words10.xml -->

   <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
   <xsl:variable name="vLower" 
        select="'abcdefgijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
   <xsl:variable name="vUpper" 
        select="'ABCDEFGIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="vwordNodes">
        <xsl:call-template name="str-split-word-del">
          <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="/"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pDelimiters" 
                          select="', .(&#9;&#10;&#13;'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="ext:node-set($vwordNodes)/*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="word">
       <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="not(position() = last())">
           <xsl:value-of 
           select="translate(substring(.,1,1),$vLower,$vUpper)"/>
           <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,2)"/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="delim">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document (test-strSplit-to-Words10.xml):**

```
<t>004.lightning crashes (live).mp3</t>
```

**the result is**:

```
004.Lightning Crashes (Live).mp3
```

**When applied to this XML document (your provided sample):**

```
dInEsh sAchdeV kApil Muk
```

**the result is**:

```
DInEsh SAchdeV KApil Muk
```

**With just a little tweek, we get this code**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
>
   <xsl:import href="strSplitWordDel.xsl"/>

   <!-- To be applied on: test-strSplit-to-Words10.xml -->

   <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
   <xsl:variable name="vLower" 
        select="'abcdefgijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
   <xsl:variable name="vUpper" 
        select="'ABCDEFGIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="vwordNodes">
        <xsl:call-template name="str-split-word-del">
          <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="/"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pDelimiters" 
                          select="', .(&#9;&#10;&#13;'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="ext:node-set($vwordNodes)/*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="word">
           <xsl:value-of 
           select="translate(substring(.,1,1),$vLower,$vUpper)"/>
           <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring(.,2), $vUpper, $vLower)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="delim">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**which now produces the wanted result**:

```
Dinesh Sachdev Kapil Muk
```

**Explanation**:

The `str-split-word-del` template of **[FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net)** can be used for tokenization with (possibly more than one) delimiters specified as a string parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another short solution. It uses pure XSL-T 2.0. I know OP had a requirement for XSL-T 1.0, but since this page is ranked #1 on Google for 'xsl-t title case function' in 2015, this seems more relevant:

```
<xsl:function name="xx:fixCase">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($text,' ')">
        <xsl:value-of select="upper-case(substring(.,1,1))" />
        <xsl:value-of select="lower-case(substring(.,2))" />
        <xsl:if test="position() ne last()">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:function>
```

Where 'xx' is your own namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this:

http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_camel-case-to-words.html

```
 <xsl:function name="functx:camel-case-to-words" as="xs:string"
                  xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com">
      <xsl:param name="arg" as="xs:string?"/>
      <xsl:param name="delim" as="xs:string"/>

      <xsl:sequence select="
       concat(substring($arg,1,1),
                 replace(substring($arg,2),'(\p{Lu})',
                            concat($delim, '$1')))
     "/>

</xsl:function>
```

and backwards:
http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_words-to-camel-case.html

```
<xsl:function name="functx:words-to-camel-case" as="xs:string"
              xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com">
  <xsl:param name="arg" as="xs:string?"/>

  <xsl:sequence select="
     string-join((tokenize($arg,'\s+')[1],
       for $word in tokenize($arg,'\s+')[position() > 1]
       return functx:capitalize-first($word))
      ,'')
 "/>

</xsl:function>
```

Answer (score 0):

This same function on XQUERY:

function Xquery to Camel Case.

```
declare function xf:toCamelCase($text as xs:string?) as xs:string{
    if(contains($text,' ')) then
        fn:concat(xf:CamelCaseWord(substring-before($text,' ')),' ', xf:toCamelCase(substring-after($text,' ')))
    else
        xf:CamelCaseWord($text)
};

declare function xf:CamelCaseWord($text as xs:string?) as xs:string{
    fn:concat( translate(substring($text,1,1),'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), 
                translate(substring($text,2,string-length($text)-1),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A very short solution, utilising EXSLT's `split()` function:

```
<xsl:variable name='text' select='"dInEsh sAchdeV kApil Muk"' />
<xsl:variable name='lowers' select='"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"' />
<xsl:variable name='uppers' select='"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"' />

<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:for-each select='str:split($text, " ")'>
        <xsl:value-of select='concat(
            translate(substring(., 1, 1), $lowers, $uppers),
            translate(substring(., 2), $uppers, $lowers),
            " "
        )' />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Working demo: http://www.xmlplayground.com/CNmKdF

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using single line expression.
Try out this

```
string-join(for $x in tokenize($text,'\s') return concat(upper-case(substring($x, 1, 1)), lower-case(substring($x, 2))),' ')
```

Note - This has been verified with Orbeon Forms formula.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with something a tiny bit different. Using another answer I got:

> A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the result of a
> call to   toddmo:proper-case#1 ("Hey", " ")

so this fixes that.

`<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:toddmo="https://todd.mo"`

```
<xsl:function name="toddmo:proper-case" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:variable name="words">
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($text,' ')">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(upper-case(substring(.,1,1)),lower-case(substring(.,2)))"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>                    
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="string-join($words,'')"/>
</xsl:function>
```

test

```
<xsl:value-of select="toddmo:proper-case('hI my name is toddmo')"/>
```

output

> Hi My Name Is Toddmo